# #ifdef not working properly?

Tags: c++, compilation, cross-platform, conditional-compilation

I am facing issues with Xcode 5.1. Everything works fine if I do this:

```
#include "glew.h"
```

But as soon as I try to make it cross-platform, it starts giving the compilation error.

```
#if defined(_APPLE_) || defined(_MACH_)
#define OS_MACOSX
#endif

#ifdef OS_MACOSX
#include "glew.h"
#else
#include <GL/glew.h>
#endif
```

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: By "doesn't exist", do you mean it can't find the file or that it's not including it because of the conditions above?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `__APPLE__` instead of `_APPLE_`. That should solve it.

Oh, and don't moan at the IDE, it's got nothing to do with the IDE. It's about where Apple's developers decided to place the GL header files (and CL header files for that matter!)

Comment: Thank you so much! Also the GL header files are from a windows/linux library (GLEW), in this case mac has a special version of GLEW hence all the trouble. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you simply need to add either a "GL" framework, or provide a proper "header search path" in your Xcode project.

Do you know the full path to the "`<GL/glew.h>`" file? If so, you can add the full path to your project settings.

Which you can do like this:
[image: Header Search Paths]

Comment: It is in a directory that doesn't have `GL/` in the path, which makes it hard to solve (in a portable way)...

Comment: Hi @MatsPetersson do you have access to the original poster's machine, so you know s/he doesn't have a "GL/" at the end of the full path to the .h file?  Also, +1 to your good answer!

Comment: Well, I do assume that files are where they "are supposed to be as per normal installation". Of course, it would also be possible to change the installation location, but that would mean code written for "Mac only" would not compile without change.